# How to change thumbnail src attribute?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I am working on a plugin that can generate a thumbnail from a URL, getting the first image from posts; it is similar to an auto thumbnail generator. I get all `img` tags, but the URL is changed. Here is my code:

```
$image_data = file_get_contents( $thumbnail );
$filename   = basename( $thumbnail );

file_put_contents( $thumbnail, $image_data );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

$attachment  = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $thumbnail, $postId );

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $thumbnail );
$res1        = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

update_post_meta( $postId, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
```

It gives me the `img` tag as:

```
 <img width="350" height="421" src="http://localhost/w/wp-content/uploads/https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-yL4P2_f5ygk/Vxx2SBGRrII/AAAAAAAANL0/pfK0uEWrRTwZuJoq0UuwxNHpXMQ4ouypQCLcB/s1600/Step%2BUp%2BRevolution%2B2012%2BDual%2BAudio%2BHindi%2BBluRay.jpg"  class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image"  alt="Step2BUp2BRevolution2B20122BDual2BAudio2BHindi2BBluRay.jpg" />
```

How can I remove `http://localhost/w/wp-content/uploads/` from the URL?

Comment: You are trying to insert a file in media library without uploading it to WordPress? Is it ?

Comment: Yes, Thats what i Want

Comment: See the answer below, you will  need `wp_handle_upload()` as well, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, I'll edit/delete if I'm wrong

---

Inspect the contents of `$thumbnail` and I bet you'll find a URI.

From the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment):

> Use absolute path and not the URI of the file.